# Should I rewrite HTTP server in socket.io

Tags: node.js, express, http, websocket, socket.io

I have the current APIs running in an express server along with MongoDB in form of HTTP requests response. I currently have the use case of a messaging system that I know requires web sockets.

Should I rewrite the whole APIs in socket.io? Or Is there any option to do it on top of the existing HTTP server

Any suggestions in this situation will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

No, the are not mutually exclusive. Keep using HTTP for things that make sense as APIs, and only add sockets for the things that require bi-directional messaging.

`socket.io` is *not* required, and it's usually better to just use plain websockets. `socket.io` is a old, large framework that's not needed.

Comment: Thank you for replying, Can I get any resources or any kind of example? It'll be helpful

Comment: @RakshithRakshak no, you have to do your own research. 'Resources of any kind' is as broad as it gets.

Comment: Thank you, I'll checkout